# Реализацией шаблонного класса с перегрузкой оператора+ и оператора<<

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Учусь программировать:) написал програмку для реализации шаблонного класса, создал массив указателей с помощью unique_ptr. Не получается реализовать перегрузку оператора+ и оператора<<. Прочитал кучу примеров и в конец запутался.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <locale>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <cstdlib>
   #include <clocale>
   #include <conio.h>
   #include<vector>
   using namespace std;


    template <class Rod> class MayClass 
   {
    Rod data{ 0 };
    Rod data2{ 0 };
    
    template <typename Rod>
    friend  ostream& operator <<(ostream & is,const MayClass<Rod> & rhs);
    
    public:
    MayClass() {  };
    MayClass(Rod d);
    ~MayClass() ;
    MayClass<Rod> &operator=(const Rod& V);
    MayClass<Rod>& operator=(MayClass<Rod>&V);
   };
     
    template<typename Rod>MayClass<Rod>& MayClass<Rod>::operator=(const Rod& V) //присваивание константы
     {
    
      data2 =V;
      cout<<setw(10) << "data2=  " << data2;
      *this = data2;
      return *this;
     }

    template<typename Rod>MayClass<Rod>& MayClass<Rod>::operator=(MayClass<Rod>& V) // присваивание объекта
    {
    data2 = V.data2;
    *this = data2;
    cout<<setw(4)<<" this=   " << *this << endl;
    return *this;
    }
    
    template <typename Rod> ostream& operator <<(ostream& is,const 
    MayClass<Rod>& rhs)
    {
    is<<setw(5) << rhs.data;
    return is;
    }
    template <class Rod> MayClass<Rod>::MayClass(Rod d)
    {
     data = d;
     data2 = d;
    }

    template <class Rod> MayClass<Rod>::~MayClass()
    {
     //cout << " Destructor  ";
    }

    int main()
    {
     MayClass<int>start(1);
     MayClass<int>start2{ 0 };
     unique_ptr<MayClass<int>[]> P(new MayClass<int>[27]);
     unique_ptr< MayClass<char>> SS(new MayClass<char>);
     int i;
     *SS ='S';// оператор= не работает для этой операции
     cout << "  *SS = " << *SS << '\n';
    
     for (i = 1; i < 27; ++i)
     {
        
        P[i] = i; //оператор= не работает для этой операции
        
        
         cout << " P["<<i<<"] = " << P[i] << "\n";
     }
        
     start2 = start; //пытался перегрузить operator= для присваивания 
     обьектов
     cout << setw(5) << "start2=  " << start2 << '\n';
     return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Сделал минимальные правки, где то так

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

template <class Rod> class MayClass {
    Rod data;
    Rod data1;
    //MayClass* next;
    
    public:
    MayClass() {  };
    MayClass(Rod d) {
        data = d;
        //next = nullptr;
    }
    ~MayClass() {}
    
    Rod getData() const { return data;}
    Rod getData1() const { return data1;}
    };

template <class Rod>MayClass <Rod> operator+(MayClass<Rod>& a,int V)
{
    // Как должена быть прописана перегрузка operator+ не знаю
    // а только Вы и знате. Но может быть так
    // Но это не точно
    return MayClass<Rod>{a.getData1() + V};
}


template<class Rod>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MayClass<Rod>& r)
{
    os << r.getData() << " " << r.getData1();
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    MayClass<int>start(1);

    std::unique_ptr<MayClass <int>[]> P(new MayClass <int>[27]);
    int i;
    
    for (i = 1; i < 26; ++i)
    {
        //*(P + i) = i;//ошибка здесь - не пишите так по сишному. не нужно.
        P[i] = i;
    
    //unique_ptr<char>SS(new char[50]);
    std::cout << " data =" << P[i] << "\n";//ошибка здесь
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не получается перегрузить operator=

Comment: То есть оператор копирующего присваивания?

Comment: Хотел перегрузить оператор = для вот этого кода: start2 = start;

Comment: я посмотрел в код - там очень страшно теперь. Попробуйте создать минимальный пример, на котором воспроизводится Ваша проблема и оформите как новый вопрос. А текст этого вопроса лучше откатить.

Comment: Постарался оставить минимальный код с пометками того что и где не получается. Надеюсь этого будет достаточно.

Comment: ох ох. ну не стоило прям тут редактировать вопрос. Иначе ответы могут потерять свой смысл.